# Dockerfiles to run AEM subsystems in containers

Tags: java, docker

As i am new to docker, i want to know how one can download cq-quickstart-6.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file. I am facing problem regards the same jar file at the time of building application.

It will be great, if i can get to know about how one can access and configure repository from git with docker start to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [AEM 6.1 / "Deploying and Maintaining" doc](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/deploy.html#par_title):

> Customers with a valid maintenance and support contract should have received a mail notification with a code and be able to download AEM from the Adobe Licensing Website.
>   Business partners can request download access from spphelp@adobe.com.

The Adobe Experience Manager(AEM) software package is available in two forms:

> - `cq-quickstart-6.1.0.jar`: A standalone executable jar file that includes everything needed to get up and running.
> - `cq-quickstart-6.1.0.war`: A war file for deployment in a third-party application server.

Once you have downloaded it, you can use it in a Dockerfile similar to the one presented in "[in-container testing for AEM with docker/](http://www.techinsight.io/review/adobe-experience-manager/incontainer-testing-for-aem-with-docker/)":

```
FROM dockerfile/java:oracle-java7

RUN mkdir /opt/aem/

WORKDIR /opt/aem/

ADD ~/Documents/demo/6.0/cq-quickstart-6.0.jar /opt/aem/cq-quickstart-6.0.jar
ADD ~/Documents/demo/6.0/license.properties /opt/aem/license.properties

RUN java -jar cq-quickstart-6.0.jar -unpack -v

RUN mkdir /opt/aem/jacoco-0.7.1.201405082137

ADD ~/Documents/demo/jacoco-0.7.1.201405082137.zip \
    /opt/aem/jacoco-0.7.1.201405082137/jacoco-0.7.1.201405082137.zip

RUN unzip jacoco-0.7.1.201405082137/jacoco-0.7.1.201405082137.zip \
          lib/* \
          -d jacoco-0.7.1.201405082137/

ENV CQ_FOREGROUND y
ENV CQ_VERBOSE    y
ENV CQ_NOBROWSER  y
ENV CQ_RUNMODE    "dev,author,nosamplecontent"
ENV CQ_JVM_OPTS   "-server -Xmx1524M -Xms512M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M \
                   -javaagent:/opt/aem/jacoco-0.7.1.201405082137/lib/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.1.201405082137.jar=output=tcpserver,port=6300"


CMD crx-quickstart/bin/quickstart
```