# Need cq-quickstart-6.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and I am unable to get how can I get access to cq-quickstart-6.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please describe what you already have, what you already tried etc...? What operating system you are working on? What tools do you use?

Comment: I answered a similar question in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35408410/6309